# How to create MSI installer with embedded resources from a Windows Form project

Tags: winforms, windows-installer, installation

I have this WinForms project (based on [this one](http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com/), but modified for SharePoint 2010) that is actually a setup wizard for installing SharePoint 2010 solution packages (.wsp).

This project besides installing the .wsp, runs some .sql scripts on a SQL Server database.

My question is **how can I create an MSI/EXE installer with all the resources (.wsp file, .sql files, images) embedded inside so I only have one file to distribute?**

Please take in mind that using a Visual Studio Setup Project is not an option because that generates an installer to install the installer. I don't need that, the WinForms project IS the installer.

Hope I'm clear enough.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Just to be clear, the WInFroms project **IS** the installer. It contains the wizard dialogs and runs the code to install the Sharepoint solution, runs the SQL scripts, etc.

When I compile the project I end up having a bunch of files with the following structure:

```
\en-us
\Resources
SomeThirdParty.dll
AnotherThirdParty.dll
Setup.application
Setup.exe
Setup.exe.config
Setup.exe.manifest
Setup.pdb
Setup.vshost.application
Setup.vshost.exe
Setup.vshost.exe.config
Setup.vshost.exe.manifest
```

What I need is a tool to package everything in a MSI installer that will auto-extract and auto-execute `setup.exe`. **NOT** a tool to generate the installer itself, the installer is already coded, it's the WinForms project itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) offers support for this, although the features you need are available only in the licensed versions. Basically, you can either create an MSI wrapper which simply launches your project and executes the SQL scripts or try to use its dedicated SharePoint support.

Another approach would be something like [IExpress](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346760.aspx). A self-extracting EXE which launches the files contained inside it.

Comment: Yes, at this point I'm just looking for a tool that generates a MSI or an EXE auto-executable from the output build of my Winforms project. I've tried IExpress but it doesn't respect the folders inside and when it extract the files are all in the root folder (and I have folders like Resources and stuff). But I do like what IExpress does. Any alternative to it?

Comment: I forgot to mention that since IExpress doesn't respect folders, the installer is unable to find some files which are supposed to be under /Resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Wix with success in the past.  http://wix.sourceforge.net/

You can embed resources in the msi so you will only have one file to distribute. Additionally any custom installation steps you need to perform can be accomplished by writing custom actions in c# or vb.net code.

Comment: I was just looking at it. My question is... I've already a WinForms project that does what I need. I don't really want to rewrite everything into WiX. Is there a way to use Wix inside an existing WinForms project and only use it to generate an unique MSI installer?

Comment: So are you saying that your winforms application actually runs the install code?  If that is the case, you may be able to use dot net installer http://dblock.github.com/dotnetinstaller/ . It basically can create an exe that contains embedded resources.  If I am understanding what you are trying to do, this may be what you need.

Comment: Yes, the winforms is actually the installer that runs everything needed to install the sharepoint solution. So yes, I don't need a full installer project, I just need a way to pack the setup project in an exe/msi auto-executable. I'll take a look at dotnetinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

Like Cosmin Pirvu mentioned, you are asking for a self-extracting installer. One I have used in the past is a free version from Chilkat Software called [ZIP 2 Secure EXE](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatsfx.asp).

If all your assemblies are .NET, then you can also try [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) to just them all into a single assembly.  Although that wouldn't help with the .manifest and .config files.

EDIT: 
An alternative to using ILMerge is embedding the dlls into your executable, [as described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx).